# Usable Software Reverse Engineering tools needed!

Tags: c, reverse-engineering

Hey guys, Myself and 2 fellow software engineer students are tasked to reverse engineer the gawk program. We need to create diagrams representing the structure, and answer questions about the program.

http://directory.fsf.org/project/gawk/

We are looking for simple to use reverse engineering tools for C programs. Our instructor has given us the following three tools as examples of what we should use, but we simply are having a huge problem getting them to work. Do you have any alternative solutions, or perhaps some good documentation on one of the following tools to help us out? Thanks!

PBS: http://www.swag.uwaterloo.ca/pbs/

RIGI: http://www.rigi.csc.uvic.ca/Pages/download.html

Shrimp: http://www.thechiselgroup.org/shrimp

Comment: do you mean reverse engineering? You are to start with the binary?

Comment: Have you explained to your instructor that the tools suggested are problematic?  This exercise shouldn't be about getting the tools to work, but rather getting experience with using the tools.

Comment: None of the tools you've linked to appear to have anything at all to do with reverse engineering a program.

Comment: I've heard that creating UML diagrams from Java (or any OO) code is also called reverse engeneering. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 5):

This graphic is supposed to *help understand* a simple C list? http://www.rigi.cs.uvic.ca/downloads/demos/list-d/ls7.html

I strongly suggest ignoring those programs and *start reading the code*.

Reading the code can be vastly simplified if you have good tools to help; [vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)) with [etags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags) and [cscope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cscope) is my preferred tool, with the GNU [id utils](http://www.gnu.org/software/idutils/) tools coming in as occasionally handy.

[Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) users will probably stick closely with just etags.

The [Eclipse IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)) can probably help you navigate through code too. I've never tried it, but enough people love it so I hope it has some nice functionality.

People often find it easy to give exact URLs to locations in Linux source code using the [lxr](http://lxr.linux.no/+trees) tool, e.g.: http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37.1/security/apparmor/lsm.c#L294  -- this system requires very little on individual client machines, which means you only need to configure it once as a server and all your classmates can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

1. As first, you can use IDA Pro under linux. For more information of reversing tools, see https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/366-software-reverse-engineering-tools.
2. Binutils includes next reversing tools:

   - file;
   - nm;
   - size;
   - strings;
   - ldd;
   - readelf.
3. Objdump – disassembler. It shows header of a program, sections of file (flag -х). Disassemble file (flag -D). It shows body of sections in hex view (flag -s).
4. EDB. It is like OllyDbg, but under Linux.
5. HTE. Сonsole editor with more functions. It can disassemble files, supports cross-reference links, set functions’ name.